# How to print a list with integers without the brackets, commas and no quotes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This is a list of Integers and this is how they are printing:

```
[7, 7, 7, 7]
```

I want them to simply print like this:

```
7777
```

I don't want brackets, commas or quotes.  What to do?

Answer (score 89):

If you're using Python 3, or appropriate Python 2.x version with `from __future__ import print_function` then:

```
data = [7, 7, 7, 7]
print(*data, sep='')
```

Otherwise, you'll need to convert to string and print:

```
print ''.join(map(str, data))
```

Comment: What does *data actually mean ?
Could you please explain ?

Comment: * opens a list. Gives the value. if `lis` is is a list, lis = [*lis]

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
print("".join(str(x) for x in This))
```

Answer (score 10):

Using `.format` from Python 2.6 and higher:

```
>>> print '{}{}{}{}'.format(*[7,7,7,7])
7777
>>> data = [7, 7, 7, 7] * 3
>>> print ('{}'*len(data)).format(*data)
777777777777777777777777
```

For Python 3:

```
>>> print(('{}'*len(data)).format(*data))
777777777777777777777777
```

Comment: i got an error from your first example.
`>>> print '{}{}{}{}'.format(*[7,7,7,7])`
`  File "<stdin>", line 1`
`    print '{}{}{}{}'.format(*[7,7,7,7])`
`                   ^`
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
`>>> `

Comment: Do not type the `>>>` part.  That is just the prompt for a  typical python command line session.

Comment: i didn't.  it's hard to format inline code in comments.  the code, as written, does not work.  i think the print command in python 3 needs parentheses.  i took the "and higher" too literally, i guess.

Answer (score 8):

You can convert it to a string, and then to an int:

```
print(int("".join(str(x) for x in [7,7,7,7])))
```

Comment: The `int()` step seems unnecessary to me...

Comment: OP did ask for "I don't want brackets, commas or **quotes**"

Comment: I dont mean to sound ignorant but I new to stackoverflow.  How do I Accept?

Comment: There should be a green checkmark on the left :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```
for element in list_:
   sys.stdout.write(str(element))
```