# How to print a list of ints to QPlainTextEdit?

Tags: python, list, pyqt, pyqt5, qplaintextedit

I have a list

```
temp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I know to print to the console as strings, I would just do

```
for i in range(0, len(temp)):
    temp[i] = str(temp[i])
```

and get

```
1
2
3
...
```

How can I do that since I don't think it can be done recursively when I setPlainText to the QPlainTextEdit? I assume I would have to remove the commas and brackets and insert \n, from which I started looking to solve my problems with this post: [How to print a list with integers without the brackets, commas and no quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757450/how-to-print-a-list-with-integers-without-the-brackets-commas-and-no-quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to convert the numbers to string and add it with [appendPlainText()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#appendPlainText):

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    temp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

    w = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
    for i in temp:
        w.appendPlainText(str(i))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Or as you point out you can use [join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```py
w.setPlainText("\n".join(map(str, temp)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QPlainTextEdit, QApplication)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    temp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    w = QPlainTextEdit()
    while temp:
        w.appendPlainText(str(temp.pop(0)))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```