# How to print a nested list in python without brackets or commas

Tags: json, python-3.7

I am working with a JSON file, below.

```
[
  {
  "text": "Now that's JSON!",
  "secret text": "Now that's some _serious_ JSON!"
},
{
  "text": "edited",
  "secret text": {"type":"Now that's some _serious_ JSON!", "coordinates":[15.3,11]}
}
]
```

I want to print to the console the coordinate as follows, without the brackets or commas.

15.3 11

```
import json

with open('message.json') as message_json:
  message = json.load(message_json)


print(message[1]['secret text']["coordinates"][:])
```

and i get the following:

```
[15.3, 11]
```

how can i print to console so that it is 15.3 11 no brackets or commas are included. and i want this to be a dynamic solution so it applies to all examples not just this.
thank you so much

Comment: Can you try `print(*message[1]['secret text']["coordinates"])` ? Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17757544/7030591

Comment: this worked.. Amazing. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Enjoy:)